# Call lightning component from external site and pass query params

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-out

I am developing a payment gateway feature in salesforce application. I have created a Lightning component where I use an iFrame to redirect to the payment gateway URL.

After payment is complete, I need to configure a passback URL from the gateway. I am thinking the URL should redirect to a lightning component. In the component, I can then access the query params from the gateway.

How can I make an external website access and pass params to lightning component?

Is lightning out an option to use in this scenario? If so can you give me specific ways to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using iframe for authenticating payment gateway, you will generally get a callback (for success or failure). You will not really redirect to any other URL. In the event of callback function, you will be provided with needed information.

Below is sample code for iframe submit:

```
$ServiceIFrame.submit({
        iFrameId: '<%IFrame Name or ID%>',
        targetUrl: '<%target URL%>',
        autosizeheight: true,
        autosizewidth: true,
        onSuccess: function (e) {
            //Successfully Iframe Loaded
        },
        onError: function (e) {
            //Error on Iframe Loading
        } 
    });
```